# Account List View Index Out of Range

Tags: c#, listview, indexing

Here is my code

```
 int totallikes = 2;
 int currentrep = 0;
 while (currentrep < totallikes)
   {
        string user = accounrLlistview.Items[currentrep].text;
        string pass = accounrLlistview.Items[currentrep].SubItems[1].text;
        //code to do whatever
        currentrep = currentrep + 1;
   }
```

The listview is created by the user prior to this button click running.

I have a listview box with a username password and an id, there are 2 collections.
user1 pass1 id1
user2 pass2 id2

im trying to get the user2

It works the first time, but on the second loop through i get the error,
InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

yes there is writing in what im trying to pull up

Comment: Chances are that when currentrep is 1, there is no second item in SubItems. Debug and put a watch on that collection and see what is in it.

Comment: The error occurs at 
string user = accounrLlistview.Items[currentrep].text;

and the item isnt blank.

Comment: How many items are in the Listview?

Comment: there are 2 items in the listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Items.Count` property to determine the **number of Items** in your `ListView` like:

```
while (currentrep < accountListview.Items.Count)
{
    string user = accounrLlistview.Items[currentrep].text;
    string pass = accounrLlistview.Items[currentrep].SubItems[1].text;
    //code to do whatever
    currentrep = currentrep + 1;
}
```

If it pass through the first traverse then the `index` '1' in `accounrLlistview.Items[currentrep].SubItems[1].text` is not the problem. And most likely instead the `currentrep` which is the index for `Items[]` here.